# Query Board challenge on Python, need some pointers

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, I have this challenge on CodeEval, but I seem don't know where to start, so I need some pointers (and answers if you can) to help me figure out this challenge.

**DESCRIPTION:**

There is a board (matrix). Every cell of the board contains one integer, which is 0 initially.

The next operations can be applied to the Query Board:

```
SetRow i x: it means that all values in the cells on row "i" have been change value to "x" after this operation. 
SetCol j x: it means that all values in the cells on column "j" have been changed to value "x" after this operation. 
QueryRow i: it means that you should output the sum of values on row "i". 
QueryCol j: it means that you should output the sum of values on column "j".
```

The board's dimensions are `256x256`

`i` and `j` are integers from `0` to `255`

`x` is an integer from `0` to `31`

**INPUT SAMPLE:**

Your program should accept as its first argument a path to a filename. Each line in this    file contains an operation of a query. E.g.

```
SetCol 32 20
SetRow 15 7
SetRow 16 31
QueryCol 32
SetCol 2 14
QueryRow 10
SetCol 14 0
QueryRow 15
SetRow 10 1
QueryCol 2
```

**OUTPUT SAMPLE:**

For each query, output the answer of the query. E.g.

```
5118
34
1792
3571
```

I'm not *that* great on Python, but this challenge is pretty interesting, although I didn't have any clues on how to solve it. So, I need some help from you guys.

Thanks!

Comment: parse the file, and then do the operation with `numpy`, what have you tried?

Comment: I don't really have time to post an answer right now, but what you could do is store the `set` operations in a `dict` and compute the sums on demand for every `query` op. This is the most space efficient and provided that the matrix is extremely sparse, also the most time efficient method.

Comment: @zhangxaochen: `numpy` is not available on the codeeval servers, I don't think.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh I forget that.. sorry ;P

Answer (score 4):

You could use a sparse matrix for this; addressed by `(col, row)` tuples as keys in a dictionary, to save memory. 64k cells is a big list otherwise (2MB+ on a 64-bit system):

```
matrix = {}
```

This is way more efficient, as the challenge is unlikely to set values for all rows and columns on the board.

Setting a column or row is then:

```
def set_col(col, x):
    for i in range(256):
        matrix[i, col] = x

def set_row(row, x):
    for i in range(256):
        matrix[row, i] = x
```

and summing a row or column is then:

```
def get_col(col):
    return sum(matrix.get((i, col), 0) for i in range(256))

def get_row(row):
    return sum(matrix.get((row, i), 0) for i in range(256))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 256, 256
board = [[0] * WIDTH for i in range(HEIGHT)]

def set_row(i, x):
    global board
    board[i] = [x]*WIDTH
```

... implement each function, then parse each line of input to decide which function to call,

```
for line in inf:
    dat = line.split()
    if dat[0] == "SetRow":
        set_row(int(dat[1]), int(dat[2]))
    elif ...
```

**Edit:** Per Martijn's comments:

- total memory usage for `board` is about 2.1MB. By comparison, after 100 random row/column writes, `matrix` is 3.1MB (although it tops out there and doesn't get any bigger).
- yes, `global` is unnecessary when modifying a global object (just don't try to assign to it).
- while dispatching from a dict is good and efficient, I did not want to inflict it on someone who is "not *that* great on Python", especially for just four entries.

For sake of comparison, how about

```
time = 0
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 256, 256
INIT = 0

rows = [(time, INIT) for _ in range(WIDTH)]
cols = [(time, INIT) for _ in range(HEIGHT)]

def set_row(i, x):
    global time
    time += 1
    rows[int(i)] = (time, int(x))

def set_col(i, x):
    global time
    time += 1
    cols[int(i)] = (time, int(x))

def query_row(i):
    rt, rv = rows[int(i)]
    total = rv * WIDTH + sum(cv - rv for ct, cv in cols if ct > rt)
    print(total)

def query_col(j):
    ct, cv = cols[int(j)]
    total = cv * HEIGHT + sum(rv - cv for rt, rv in rows if rt > ct)
    print(total)

ops = {
    "SetRow": set_row,
    "SetCol": set_col,
    "QueryRow": query_row,
    "QueryCol": query_col
}

inf = """SetCol 32 20
SetRow 15 7
SetRow 16 31
QueryCol 32
SetCol 2 14
QueryRow 10
SetCol 14 0
QueryRow 15
SetRow 10 1
QueryCol 2""".splitlines()

for line in inf:
    line = line.split()
    op = line.pop(0)
    ops[op](*line)
```

which only uses 4.3k of memory for rows[] and cols[].

**Edit2:**

using your code from above for matrix, set_row, set_col,

```
import sys

for n in range(256):
    set_row(n, 1)
    print("{}: {}".format(2*(n+1)-1, sys.getsizeof(matrix)))
    set_col(n, 1)
    print("{}: {}".format(2*(n+1), sys.getsizeof(matrix)))
```

which returns (condensed:)

```
1: 12560
2: 49424
6: 196880
22: 786704
94: 3146000
```

... basically the allocated memory quadruples at each step. If I change the memory measure to include key-tuples,

```
def get_matrix_size():
    return sys.getsizeof(matrix) + sum(sys.getsizeof(key) for key in matrix)
```

it increases more smoothly, but still takes a bit jump at the above points:

```
5  :  127.9k
6  :  287.7k

21 :  521.4k
22 : 1112.7k

60 : 1672.0k
61 : 1686.1k   <-- approx expected size on your reported problem set

93 : 2121.1k
94 : 4438.2k
```

Comment: 256 * 256 is 65k integer numbers. That's way more memory than needed.

Comment: You are only altering indices in `board`, no need to mark it as a global here.

Comment: And a dictionary holding functions is easier than a lot of `if` statements; `commands = {'SetRow': setrow, ...}`.

Comment: I rigged the test runner and was given 69 sets, 81 queries. 31 unique rows were set, 29 unique columns. I measure 1.7 MB for the result.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: on my system (Win7, Python 2.7.5, 64-bit) `matrix` used .75MB until the 93rd row-write. At that point, it jumped to 3.06MB and stayed there. I may have arbitrarily chosen 100 row-writes as my comparison point ;-)

Comment: That is a huge jump; how do you measure memory use? I use `sys.getsizeof()` on the dictionary, plus no all the tuples for the keys, plus on all the unique values (all ints are in the range 0-31 so are interned; only ever one copy in memory per int).

Comment: Note: I have seen the codeeval.com memory measurements go way off when running Python. I've got a few scores hitting the maximum as the process was measured as having used 4096 bytes of memory. Something is wonky on their servers. :-)